# donuts sprinkles look like paper (no thickness)

Tags: rendering

I follow the instruction of this series blender donuts video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0. When I render my model, I found that the sprinkles on the icing look like paper without any thickness. See the screenshot.

[image]

If you have any ideas, I hope that you can help me. Thank you so much! [Here](https://hu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hongsuwang_fas_harvard_edu/Ee2DL6kCMwdErcfWsmIu4sABw9c_yc3GD_jL0Jv1bMqfSw?e=PHvDxk) is the blender file.

Answer (score 4):

It is just a **scale problem**.
If you select one of your sprinkles object, you will see that its scale is not `1` :

[image: Scale of one of the sprinkles]

A scale other than `1` often cause problems like this. Problems appear mostly when you use the object as a particle or when you add modifiers etc...

You must always pay a close attention to scale and you always sould have your objects at scale of `1` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

For your problem, just [applying](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#transforms) the scale would solve it. Select **all** your sprinkles and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose `Scale` :

[image: Apply scale]

Now the sprinkles look just fine :

[image: Sprinkles are fine]

Just don't forget to plug the nodes in the node editor since, for some reason, they were not plugged in the file you uploaded :

[image: Nodes]

Comment: Personally, I would go further, and suggest: '**Never** scale in object mode, while modelling'.  Half the questions on this forum would disappear. But I'm probably bossier than you.  :)

Comment: That's right though. You should never scale in Object mode and if for whatever reason you do, you should apply the scale unleass there's a really good reason.

Comment: Yup.. object-level scaling is for animation. Otherwise, one legitimate use comes to mind: re-scaling to dimensions, in the 'Dimensions' panel. (And Ctrl-A applying straight away, as you say)

Comment: Thank you so much, my friends! It's really very helpful! I will pay more attend to the scales in the future.