# UV Unwrap not scaling correctly

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Upon smart UV wrapping a toolbox, this happens:

[image]

As you can see the UV map is stretched. This is problematic as the pixels need to be perfectly square.

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you apply the scale with `Ctrl+A` *> Scale* ? otherwise share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Important: apply the scale in _Object Mode_, this is nothing to be done in _Edit Mode_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well as pointed out in the comments by @HarryMcKenzie, it's probably a scale problem. If the scale of your object is not `(1, 1, 1)` then your UVs are going to be streched when you unwrap it with `Smart UV Project` :

[image: streched texture due to bad scale]

The simplest solution would be (if you don't want to readjust all the UV manually) to **apply the scale and then reunwrap the object** :

[image: texture applied correctly]

I would (strongly) suggest that you allways pay attention to the scale of your object when working with Blender or any other software for that matter and allways make sure your scale is at `1` unless you have a good reason. Scale value other than `1` can lead to [other kinds of problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/295178/115533). And as Robbin Betts says :

> Personally, I would go further, and suggest: 'Never scale in object mode, while modelling'. Half the questions on this forum would disappear. But I'm probably bossier than you. :)

I hope I helped.